# How to check the following two connected open sets coincide?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

As subsets of a Hilbert space (we don't present the concret space here), if $A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2$ are open sets satisfying
\begin{equation}
A_1 \cap B_1=A_2\cap B_2 =\emptyset, \quad A_1 \cup B_1=A_2 \cup B_2.
\end{equation}
Moreover, $A_1$ and $A_2$ have the point $0$ in common, and they are both **connected** sets, then can we conclude that $A_1=A_2$?

Comment: Yes, but is this a home-work exercice?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh The question is from Schlag & Nakanish: Invariant manifolds and Dispersive Hamiltonian Evolution Equations. The proof of Lemma 4.8 applies the conclusion above. But I do not know how to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A_1=A_1\cap(A_1 \cup B_1)=A_1\cap(A_2\cup B_2)=(A_1\cap A_2)\cup(A_1\cap B_2)$$

Thus $A_1\cap A_2 =A_1$ or $A_1 \cap A_2=\emptyset$, as $A_1$ connected.  The latter cannot happen as $0\in A_1 \cap A_2$.  We conclude $A_1\subseteq A_2$.

By the same argument $A_2\subseteq A_1$ and we have $A_1=A_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this applies to any topological space, not only Hilbert spaces (of course $0$ is then replaced with an arbitrary point).

For $i=1,2$ we have that $A_i,B_i$ are disjoint and open and $A_i$ is connected. It follows that $A_i$ is a connected component of $A_i\cup B_i$. Since $0\in A_i$ then $A_i$ is the connected component of $0$. But connected components of a given point are unique, meaning $A_1=A_2$.